# Can't get onclick to fire with combobox

Tags: javascript, combobox

I have a set of three option boxes which I am trying to keep disabled until the previous box has chosen. I am trying to use the `onchange` event to fire some script which enables the following box and populates the options but cannot get it to work for some reason? `#nap2` is the first combo box, `#nap4` the following. The code works fine on a `click` event but I need it to happen after the user has selected an option....

**HTML**

```
<select id="nap2" class="napkeeComponent napkeeCombobox">
      <option>Rider 1</option>
      <option>Rider 2</option>
      <option>Rider 3</option>
      <option>Rider 4</option>
      <option>Rider 5</option>
</select>

<select id="nap4" class="napkeeComponent napkeeCombobox" disabled>
      <option>Bike1</option>
      <option>Bike2</option>
      <option>Bike3</option>
      <option>Bike4</option>
      <option>Bike5</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#nap2").onchange(function(event){
var element = document.getElementById("nap2");
var selected = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    if(selected == "Rider 1"){
            $('#nap4').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
        if((selected == "Rider 2")){
            $('#nap4').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }   
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `onchange` event instead there is `.on('change'` or `.change`. so use either of one as below:

```
$("#nap2").on('change',function(event){
var element = document.getElementById("nap2");
var selected = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;
    if(selected == "Rider 1"){
            $('#nap4').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else{
        if((selected == "Rider 2")){
            $('#nap4').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    }   
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4vdw2y4g/)**

More simplified version:

```
$("#nap2").on('change',function(event){
    var selected = $(this).find('option:selected').text() //get selected text
    if(selected == "Rider 1" || selected =="Rider 2"){ //have a single condition with or
        $('#nap4').removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
        $('#nap4').attr('disabled',true); //In case you want to disable it again if different option is selected
});
```

**[DEMO +](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/4vdw2y4g/1/)**

Comment: Fantastic - for some reason .on('change') would not work but .change did!

Comment: depends on the `jquery` version you use! what version of `jquery` you are using? If it is higher than or equal `1.7` then it will work

Comment: 1.7.2 - weird :/ Is there a similar method that fires when the dropdown arrow is pressed? The reason I ask is because if the box starts with rider 1 in and is opened but the user then chooses rider 1 obviously there has been no change so the script will not trigger.

Comment: why don't you keep some default value on `select` like `Select something`